# Swift ui mac os extension delegate view is possible

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, delegates

I have the following code, which clicking on the button allows me to `clone` a `repository` that is on `github`.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Git

struct File: View {
    @State var pathUrl = "https://github.com/way-to-code/git-macOS.git"
    @State var nameDir = "/Users/"
    
    func cloneReport() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            let url: URL = URL(string: pathUrl)!
            let report = GitRepository(from: url)
            //report.delegate = progressTracker
            do {
                try report.clone(at: nameDir)
            } catch let e {
                print("Errors \(e).")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            cloneReport()
        }) {
            Text("Clone").frame(width: 330)
        }
    }
}

struct File_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        File()
    }
}
```

I am using the following [framework](https://github.com/way-to-code/git-macOS#receiving-the-progress) that tells me if I want to implement the `delegate` of the `framework` protocol for track events, I have to do this:

```swift
let progressTracker = MyCustomObject()

let repository: GitRepository
repository.delegate = progressTracker

// implement RepositoryDelegate protocol in order to track the events
extension MyCustomObject: RepositoryDelegate {
 func repository(_ repository: Repository, didProgressClone progress: String) {
 }
}
```

I can't do `extension` of a class that doesn't exist gives me the following error: `Cannot find type 'MyCustomObject' in scope`

is it possible to extend a `struct` of type `View`?

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

An example, the author saying to create or use MyCustomObject class for delegates.

You have to create one class for tracking.

First, create one class same as MyCustomObject

```
class ProgressTracker: RepositoryDelegate {
    func repository(_ repository: Repository, didProgressClone progress: String) {
        print(progress) // Here you will get progress
    }
}
```

And configure inside the view

```
struct File: View {
    @State var pathUrl = "https://github.com/way-to-code/git-macOS.git"
    @State var nameDir = "/Users/"
    
    let progressTracker = ProgressTracker()  // << === Here
    
    func cloneReport() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            let url: URL = URL(string: pathUrl)!
            let report = GitRepository(from: url)
            report.delegate = progressTracker // << === Here
            
            do {
                try report.clone(at: nameDir)
            } catch let e {
                print("Errors \(e).")
            }
        }
    }
```

---

---

If you want your progress inside the File View you can set up your view like this.

```
struct File: View {
    @State var pathUrl = "https://github.com/way-to-code/git-macOS.git"
    @State var nameDir = "/Users/"
    
    var progressTracker = ProgressTracker()  // << === Here
    
    func cloneReport() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            let url: URL = URL(string: pathUrl)!
            let report = GitRepository(from: url)
            report.delegate = progressTracker // << === Here
            
            progressTracker.progressBlock = { progress in // << === Here
                print(progress)
            }
            
            do {
                try report.clone(at: nameDir)
            } catch let e {
                print("Errors \(e).")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            cloneReport()
        }) {
            Text("Clone").frame(width: 330)
        }
    }
}

// implement RepositoryDelegate protocol in order to track the events
class ProgressTracker: RepositoryDelegate {
    lazy var progressBlock: ((String) -> Void)? = nil
    
    func repository(_ repository: Repository, didProgressClone progress: String) {
        self.progressBlock?(progress)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you say, the problem that nothing is printed on me.
I tried the `repository` function located inside `ProgressTracker`.
I also tried inside the `progressBlock` inside the `View`.

Comment: It seems that the `repository` function is never called.

Comment: I also tried defining an empty class first and then defining the function inside an extension, but it doesn't work anyway.